# Issue with SSRS Subscriptions

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Currently, all of our subscriptions are failing with following error:

```
ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: AuthzInitializeContextFromSid: Win32 error: 5; possible reason - service account doesn't have rights to check domain user SIDs., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error.
```

I tried giving some additional access to the Network Service account under ReportServerdb, but it still failed.  I tried restarting reporting services, but that didn't fix it either.  I even asked them to confirm following:

```
Add the Windows account to the Pre-Windows 2000 Compatibility Access group by using the Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in.

Add the Windows account to the Windows Authorization Access group by using the Active Directory Users and Computers snap-in.

Restart the computer that is running Reporting Services.
```

One strange thing I noticed was I am able to send subscriptions if I do not attach anything.  Example:  If I only choose to "include link", it works.  Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: It sounds like your service account needs access to the windows server, not the SQL Server.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli you should add this as the answer rather than a comment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer...It sounds like your service account needs access to the windows server, not the SQL Server.  The fact that your subscription works fine without an attachment indicates the service account does not have adequate  access to the file system necessary to create the file.

It would be difficult at best to advise on what is needed where without knowing how your report server is configured.  You can get options and permissions settings for your version and configuration from [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: I'll accept your answer! Our customer refuses to believe the service account needs additional access. We finally had to tell them to contact Microsoft.  Not sure what happened after that, but we also believed it was access related issue.